# More information required about Site Usage Reports in SharePoint 2007

Tags: sharepoint-2007

Can anyone point me in the direction of more detailed information about all the Site Usage Reports in SharePoint 2007. I'm trying to find out more about how the values are calculated and where they come from (for example, is it page views vs page edits or both).

Also which log files they statistics are collected from (SharePoint or IIS?).

I'm particularly interested in information about "Site Usage Summary" and "Site collection users".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check Mark Arend's MSDN blog entry. The attached word document explains how every metric is calculated, what it means, and where it can be found.

- [Original blog entry on MSDN](http://blogs.msdn.com/markarend/archive/2008/09/06/moss-usage-reports-explained.aspx)
- [The attached word document](http://blogs.msdn.com/markarend/attachment/8927809.ashx)
- [An HTML translated version of that word document](https://sharepoint.missouri.edu/wiki/Wiki%20Pages/MOSS%20Usage%20Reports%20explained.aspx)

Comment: Excellent resources, especially the HTML translated version which also contains the stored procedures used to pull the data.